# How to debug PHP error to identify parent class

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is a SmartJobBoard software and I don't know how below errors are generated:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object in /home/_web/html/engjobs/system/lib/classifieds/SearchEngine/SearchSqlTranslator.php on line 21
```

I went to find this file `SearchSqlTranslator.php` and the below code is the function that has getType:

```
function buildSQLQuery($criteria, &$valid_criterion_number, $sorting_fields, $inner_join = false, $count = false, $relevance = false)
    {
        foreach ($criteria['common'] as $crit) {
            foreach($crit as $criterion) {
                $type = $criterion->getProperty()->getType();
                if ($criterion->getProperty() !== null && $type == 'monetary') {
                    $this->isMonetary = true;
                    break;
                }
                if ($criterion->getProperty() !== null && $criterion->getProperty()->isComplex()) {
                    $this->isComplex = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($relevance)
            $this->isRelevance = true;
        $sorting_block = $this->_getSortingStatement($sorting_fields);
        if ($count)
            $select_block = $this->_getSelectCountStatement();
        elseif ($relevance)
            $select_block = $this->_getSelectRelevanceStatement($relevance);
        else
            $select_block = $this->_getSelectStatement();
        $from_block = $this->_getFromStatement($inner_join);
        $where_block = $this->_getWhereStatement($criteria);

        $group_block = '';
        if (SJB_DB::table_exists($this->object_table_prefix.'_properties'))
            $group_block = $this->_getGroupStatement();

        $having_block = '';
        if ($this->valid_criterion_number != 0 && !empty($group_block)) {
            $having_block = " HAVING `count` = {$this->valid_criterion_number} ";
        }
        $limit_block = '';
        if ($this->limit)
            $limit_block = ' LIMIT ' . $this->limit;

        $valid_criterion_number = $this->valid_criterion_number;
        return $select_block . $from_block . $where_block . $group_block . $having_block . $sorting_block . $limit_block;
    }
```

Now I have seen the class file and it is obvious that the function is being called from somewhere else. So how am I supposed to find which class is calling this function?

Do I have to guess and go through every class file to find where it is or could I probably use something like `grep` on shell to potentially find this function and its class?

It seems though there are multiple layers (6-7 times at least) and it's very difficult to trace back if something like this error occurs. Is there a way to systematically debug these kind of problems?

Also the function above is part of `class SJB_SearchSqlTranslator` and it does not extend to any other classes.

Smart Job Board script uses Zend as its library but it seems they have created their own framework.

Comment: This line is not correct `$type = $criterion->getProperty()->getType();`? Start with `echo get_class($criterion)` and check methods get and set property.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an error/exception handler, generating a stack trace on errors like these. That way you'd get the full call stack. Error handler would be attached with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and you can get the stack trace with [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

There's an example in [this manual comment](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php#68642):

```
<?php
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
  echo 'Into '.__FUNCTION__.'() at line '.__LINE__.
  "\n\n---ERRNO---\n". print_r( $errno, true).
  "\n\n---ERRSTR---\n". print_r( $errstr, true).
  "\n\n---ERRFILE---\n". print_r( $errfile, true).
  "\n\n---ERRLINE---\n". print_r( $errline, true).
  "\n\n---ERRCONTEXT---\n".print_r( $errcontext, true).
  "\n\nBacktrace of errorHandler()\n".
  print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
}

function a( )
{
  //echo "a()'s backtrace\n".print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
  asdfasdf; // oops
}

function b()
{
  //echo "b()'s backtrace\n".print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
  a();
}

b();
```

Comment: Also, installing [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) will give such a backtrace as its default exception rendering.